# How to get the 'textareafor' line by line to ActionMethod MVC C#

Tags: c#, model-view-controller

As the title suggest, I am trying to get textarea line by line into a parameter in my action method.

This is my Jquery function:

```
        $("#number").on("click", function () {
        var numbers                  = $("#numbertextarea")[0].value

        window.location.href = ('/model/AddNumber?number=' + number)
    });
```

My Action Method:

```
public ActionResult AddNumber(string[] numbers)`
{
   //a lot of code...
}
```

Whenver I click the button it displays everything in single line like that:

```
ghjgghjgjgjgjgj
```

Instead of taking each line of string from textarea to an array, for example:

```
ghj

ggh

jgjgjgjgjgj
```

**I tried to use this:**

```
<span style="white-space: pre-line">@Model.InputNumber</span>
```

**And this:**

```
            var lines = Request["InputNumber"].Split(new string[] { Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

None of the above solutions work. The first solution just displays the string the same way in a single line - **dadaggfhge**. The other Solution returns null because at the time this action method is clicked, the model is new and do properties are null, which is the way it should be.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Split textarea's value on new line to get values as array.

Parameter name in url `'/model/AddNumber?number='` does not match the parameter name of action which is `numbers` (note missing **s**)

```
 $("#number").on("click", function () {
    var numbers = $("#numbertextarea").val().split(/\n/);

    window.location.href = ('/model/AddNumber?numbers=' + numbers)
});
```

Comment: Hi, thanks that did it. returned the string in this format: aweaw , weae , werr. just need to use now regex to split it and should be fine! :)